# In LESS, how to use a variable inside another?

Tags: less

Variable `@screen-xs-max` is a Bootstrap 3 variable. In my mixin, I'd like to use `@class` variable to get the Bootstrap variable, dynamically.

Here is a not working solution:

```
.make-btn-block (@class) {
  @media (max-width: @screen-@{class}-min) {
    // Code
  }
}

.make-btn-block(xs);
```

Another not working solution:

```
~"@{@screen-@{class}-min}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [referencing variables by name](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-names). E.g.:

```
.make-btn-block(@device) {
    @max: "screen-@{device}-max";
    @media (max-width: @@max) {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I avoid the use of "temp" variables?